# AspnetPublishHandler with name "Custom" was not found when publishing ASP.NET 5 project to Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, ubuntu-15.04

I am trying to publish a non-modified ASP.NET 5 project to my freshly installed Ubuntu 15.04 server, but I receive the following message:

> An error occurred during publish. AspnetPublishHandler with name
>   "Custom" was not found

I bound the server to the correct port with:

```
docker daemon -H 0.0.0.0:5555 &
```

The connection validation is successful. Anyone has an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried after the latest release? For some configuration combination the publish profile was getting generated incorrectly.

Comment: Let me try this when I am home :)

Comment: I have got it deploying, unfortunately its giving me a 404 error after deployment when trying to access the url...